# Disqus comments cause "clickable elements too close together" in Google Search Console mobile usabality report

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, mobile, usability, googlebot-mobile

I just got an email from Google that they found some problems on my site:

- clickable elements too close together
- Content wider than screen

I fetched problematic URLs as Googlebot and noticed that it is most likely caused by Disqus. Here's how Google sees my Disqus comments:

[image]

The elements are indeed to close but I don't think that I can change that (everything looks normal to real users). Does anyone have any idea how can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Did Google tell you which specific tap targets were too close together? I think they do, though they might have changed that.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I disabled Disqus and did the test again - it's not his fault. I see that many people have the same issue. I think it's something on Google's side